# Send Push notification text to UItableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, parse-platform, apple-push-notifications

I am handling my push notification in the following method in the app delegate:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    [PFPush handlePush:userInfo];
    NSString *pushtext = [userInfo objectForKey:@"alert"];
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"News", "")
                                                    message:pushtext
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                          otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];



}
```

As you can see, I am displaying the notification in a UIAlertview. In addition to this, i want to be able to "save" the most recent 5 notifications received to a UITableview for the user to view at a later date.

How would I a) pass the data to a UITableview and b)save the data for later viewing (possibly through NSUserdefaults?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retrieve the current push notification's text in the AppDelegate and add it to an array.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

[...]

{
    NSMutableArray *alertTextArray = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"alertTextArray"];
        NSDictionary *notifKey = launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];

    if (notifKey)
    {
        [alertTextArray addObject:[notifKey objectForKey:@"alert"]];
    }

[...]

}
```

...and this is how you can save it for later use:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:alertTextArray forKey:@"alertTextArray"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

Comment: How then would i retrieve the 5 most recent Alerts from NSuserdefaults? and how do I display each one of the alert's in their own row in a UITableview